# JDK7, mvn-3.2.2 - maven-enforcer-plugin - RequireJavaVersion failed

Tags: maven, maven-3, java-7, pom.xml

I'm using `JDK 1.7.0_60` and `maven-3.2.2`. When I run `mvn clean install` on my project `new-project`, I get the following error-

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ new-project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (default) @ new-project ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.7.0-60 is not in the allowed range [1.5,1.6,1.7.0-60).
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.621 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-10T20:37:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (default) on project new-project: Some Enforcer rules have failed.
Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here are parts of my `pom.xml` as I cannot share the complete content-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <source>1.7.0-60</source>
        <target>1.7.0-60</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>
    org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5
            </classpathContainer>
        </classpathContainers>
        <additionalConfig>
            <file>
                <name>
                    .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
                </name>
                <content>
    eclipse.preferences.version=1${line.separator}encoding/&lt;project&gt;=UTF-8${line.separator}
                </content>
            </file>
        </additionalConfig>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <rules>
            <requireJavaVersion>
                <version>[1.5,1.6,1.7.0-60)</version>
            </requireJavaVersion>
            <requireMavenVersion>
                <version>[3.2.2,)</version>
            </requireMavenVersion>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>
            ${project.basedir}/src/main/javadoc;${project.basedir}/src/main/java
        </sourcepath>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
        <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
        <links>
            <link>
                http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
            </link>
        </links>
        <source>1.7.0-60</source>
        <show>protected</show>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <reports>
                <report>javadoc</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include version 1.7.0-30 in the accepted [range](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html), then you have to use square brackets when you declare the range. And you can leave out version 1.6 as it is included in the range:

```
<requireJavaVersion>
    <version>[1.5,1.7.0-60]</version>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

Comment: Please use an up-to-date version of maven-enforcer-plugin (1.3.1).